# How to use Spinner in Recyclerview?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-spinner

Which are the best practice to handle a Spinner in a `RecyclerView` Adapter?

**This is my `RecyclerView` Adapter:**

```
public class CartAdapter extends BaseAdapter<Object> {

public CartAdapter(AbstractBaseActivity activity) {
    super(activity);
}

public static final int TYPE_PRODOTTO = 1;
public static final int TYPE_SCONTO = 2;

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {

    if (items.get(position) instanceof Article)
        return TYPE_PRODOTTO;
    else
        return TYPE_SCONTO;
}

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View rowView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(viewType == TYPE_PRODOTTO ? R.layout.item_cart : R.layout.item_cart_sconto, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(rowView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    final ViewHolder viewHolder = (ViewHolder) holder;

    final Object object = items.get(position);

    if (object instanceof Article) {

        viewHolder.getBinding().setVariable(BR.article, object);
        viewHolder.getBinding().executePendingBindings();

        assert viewHolder.quantitySpinner != null;
        assert viewHolder.cartoneQuantity != null;
        assert viewHolder.cartoneValue != null;

        CartSpinnerAdapter adapter = (CartSpinnerAdapter) viewHolder.quantitySpinner.getAdapter();
        adapter.clear();
        adapter.setCount(((Article) object).getQuantityAvailable());
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        viewHolder.quantitySpinner.setSelection(((Article) object).getQuantity() - 1); //In teoria qui la quantità non deve mai essere zero

        viewHolder.cartoneQuantity.setVisibility(position % 2 == 1 ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE); //Controllo da togliere in futuro
        viewHolder.cartoneValue.setVisibility(position % 2 == 1 ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE); //Controllo da togliere in futuro
    }

    final PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(getContext(), viewHolder.deleteMenu);
    MenuInflater inflater = popup.getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.delete_menu, popup.getMenu());

    viewHolder.deleteMenu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            popup.show();
        }
    });

    popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
            if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_delete) {
                removeData(holder.getAdapterPosition());
                ((CartActivity) activity).checkIfEmpty();
            }

            return true;
        }
    });
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    @BindView(R.id.item)
    View item;
    @Nullable
    @BindView(R.id.cart_image)
    ImageView cartImage;
    @BindView(R.id.delete_menu)
    ImageView deleteMenu;
    @Nullable
    @BindView(R.id.product_cartone_quantity)
    TextView cartoneQuantity;
    @Nullable
    @BindView(R.id.product_cartone_value)
    TextView cartoneValue;
    @Nullable
    @BindView(R.id.quantity_spinner)
    AppCompatSpinner quantitySpinner;

    private ViewDataBinding binding;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
        binding = DataBindingUtil.bind(itemView);
        if (quantitySpinner != null)
            quantitySpinner.setAdapter(new CartSpinnerAdapter(itemView.getContext(), R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item));
    }

    public ViewDataBinding getBinding() {
        return binding;
    }
}
}
```

**and this is my `Spinner` Adapter:**

```
public class CartSpinnerAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

LayoutInflater inflater;

int count;

public CartSpinnerAdapter(Context context, int resource) {
    super(context, resource);

    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

public CartSpinnerAdapter(Context context, int resource, int count) {
    super(context, resource);

    this.count = count;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

public void setCount(int count) {
    this.count = count;
}

@Override
public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    return getStandardView(position, parent, true);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    return getStandardView(position, parent, false);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return count;
}

private View getStandardView(int position, ViewGroup parent, boolean dropdown) {
    View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item, parent, false);

    TextView title = (TextView) row.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);

    title.setText(String.valueOf(position + 1));

    if (dropdown)
        title.setMinWidth(Utils.dpToPx(getContext(), 64));
    else
        title.setAlpha(0.5f);

    return row;
}
}
```

In this way when i scroll the `RecyclerView` i'm experiencing lag.

**If i remove these lines everything works fine:**

```
CartSpinnerAdapter adapter = (CartSpinnerAdapter) viewHolder.quantitySpinner.getAdapter();
adapter.clear();
adapter.setCount(((Article) object).getQuantityAvailable());
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

So the problem is the way i handle the adapter of the `Spinner`, how can i handle this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Short**

To improve performance,

1. Remove allocations from **onBindViewHolder**
2. Reuse **LayoutInflater**, instead of getting a new one every time.
3. Minimize repetitive work in **onBindViewHolder** implementation
4. **Spinner Adapter** should also recycle the views

**Background**

When using an adapter for scrolling, the most important thing to make sure is that we **DON'T** allocate new objects (or minimize it as possible).

The whole purpose of a RecyclerView with an Adapter is to make sure we Recycle our objects so that the work needed during scroll is minimal.

Since allocating memory is very "expensive", to improve scrolling performance, the first thing to look for is allocations during the **onBindViewHolder**. All allocations if any should be made in the **onCreateViewHolder**.

Once all allocations are cleared, if we still have lagging, it is time for some micro improvements. These includes improving code quality, reuse logic results, etc.

**What to do?**

1) Remove allocations from **onBindViewHolder**

In the following code:

```
final PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(getContext(), viewHolder.deleteMenu);
MenuInflater inflater = popup.getMenuInflater();
inflater.inflate(R.menu.delete_menu, popup.getMenu());

viewHolder.deleteMenu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        popup.show();
    }
});

popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_delete) {
            removeData(holder.getAdapterPosition());
            ((CartActivity) activity).checkIfEmpty();
        }

        return true;
    }
});
```

You currently have 3 direct allocations (**new**) and some indirect allocations (**inflate**). Change this code so that all allocations are in the **onCreateViewHolder**. For example:

In **onCreateViewHolder** do the allocations like so:

```
// Allocate Listener only ONCE per recycled view 
viewHolder.deleteMenu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        // Get needed data from the view TAG, we will set it later
        final int itemPosition = (Integer)view.getTag();

        // Do work only when needed - when user clicked the button
        final PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(getContext(), viewHolder.deleteMenu);
        MenuInflater inflater = popup.getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.delete_menu, popup.getMenu());

        popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                // Do logic using itemPosition etc
                return true;
            }
        });

        popup.show();
    }
});
```

In **onBindViewHolder** bind relevant data like so:

```
viewHolder.deleteMenu.setTag(holder.getAdapterPosition());
```

2) Reuse **LayoutInflater**, instead of getting a new one every time.

In the following code:

```
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View rowView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(viewType == TYPE_PRODOTTO ? R.layout.item_cart : R.layout.item_cart_sconto, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(rowView);
}
```

You are getting a new LayoutInflater every time. It is a waste. Better to get one in the Adapter constructor and save it as a member.

3) Minimize repetitive work in **onBindViewHolder** implementation

For example, in the following code:

```
viewHolder.cartoneQuantity.setVisibility(position % 2 == 1 ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE); //Controllo da togliere in futuro
viewHolder.cartoneValue.setVisibility(position % 2 == 1 ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE); //Controllo da togliere in futuro
```

You are calculating the same logic twice. Better to calculate it once and reuse the outcome:

```
int cartoneVisibility = position % 2 == 1 ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE;
viewHolder.cartoneQuantity.setVisibility(cartoneVisibility); //Controllo da togliere in futuro
viewHolder.cartoneValue.setVisibility(cartoneVisibility); //Controllo da togliere in futuro
```

4)**Spinner Adapter** should also recycle the views

In `CartSpinnerAdapter.getView()` you are also allocating memory. It happens (every time * list item * count) - That is a lot of allocations. Please use the convertView instead. Have a look on this tutorial [dzone.com/articles/android-listview-optimizations](https://dzone.com/articles/android-listview-optimizations)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. I'm experiencing the lag problem since i added the adapter logic to the spinner and even with these improvements the lag problem will not solve. So my real question is, how can i use a spinner adapter inside a recyclerview adapter?

Comment: Also, apply suggestions to the CartSpinnerAdapter. There you are not using the adapter correctly since you do not recycle the views. Use the convertView.

Comment: The lag is caused by these lines:

   "CartSpinnerAdapter adapter = (CartSpinnerAdapter) viewHolder.quantitySpinner.getAdapter();

        adapter.clear();

        adapter.setCount(((Article) object).getQuantityAvailable());

        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();"

Comment: So, as I said, in CartSpinnerAdapter. getView you are allocating memory. It happens every time * list item * count - That is a lot of allocations. Where in fact you need 0 allocations. Please use the convertView instead.  Have a look on this tutorial https://dzone.com/articles/android-listview-optimizations

Comment: Thanks @Eyal Biran, this solves the problem. Can you update your answer with this solution at the top for the next users with the same problem?

Comment: Nice solution, but i can not find binding part in this solution, while question is having some binding part

Comment: @RRR, in this case the "Binding" is the setCount function. In other cases we might have other bindings. In any case, the most important thing to remember is that we should not allocate memory within functions that are being called rapidly during UI layout. Find the allocations, get them out, and you are golden :)

Comment: Although rest seems quite fine, this part is not right "Reuse LayoutInflater, instead of getting a new one every time". Second, `LayoutInflater.inflate()` is a static member function to inflate, you can't reuse it. In case you mean reusing inflated view, in that case, you'll attach the view to the root which will throw an exception.

Comment: @Farid If you are using the static LayoutInflater.inflate() you will use the global app context which is not desired for some cases. Instead you should indeed create a LayoutInflater for the current context using LayoutInflater.from(context). The problem with doing  that is that it creates a new LayoutInflater which is not optimal thing to do inside the adapter - instead you should do it somewhere that is called once - like the ctor - and save it. Then you can use the same instance.